# Why does a value '-' (hyphen) in "tag-order" style prevent matching of the "executables" tag even if that tag is explicitly specified?

Tags: zsh

With the code below, everything works as expected:

- When I write `c` and hit the `TAB` key, I get the appropriate completions in correct order.

  [image]
- When I write `./` and hit the `TAB` key, I get the completion for the `executables` tag.

  [image]

---

```
# Always use menu selection when using unambiguous completions.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' menu 'select'

# Show only completions.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' completer _complete

# Group name becomes the name of the matching tag.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' group-name ''

# Configure the order of tag matching as well as their descriptions.
zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            functions:Functions:Functions
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords"
          )
'

# Configure the order in which completion groups will be shown.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' group-order 'Executables' 'Builtins' 'Commands' 'Aliases' 'Functions' 'Variables' 'Keywords'

# Configure the format for each group/tag description.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format $'%{\e[0;38;2;0;0;0;48;2;200;150;0m%} %d %{\e[0;38;2;200;150;0;48;2;0;0;0m%}%{\e[0m%}'

# Initialize completion system.
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

However if the tags that I've specified do not produce any completion, other tags will be tried as well.

Easiest way to prove this is to exclude the `functions` tag from `tag-order` style:

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords"
          )
'
```

and then create 2 functions with a unique prefix:

```
function unique_prefix_A() { }
function unique_prefix_B() { }
```

Now when I write `unique_prefix_` and hit the `TAB` key, I don't expect to see anything since `functions` tag was removed from `tag-order`.
However, because `Executables`, `Builtins`, `Commands`, `Aliases`, `Variables` and `Keywords` didn't provide any completions, `zsh` will by default try to match other tags, namely the excluded `functions` tag, to try to give any completion.

Because of this, the functions `unique_prefix_A` and `unique_prefix_B` will be suggested:

[image]

I don't like this behavior and want to limit the search only to tags that I have explicitly specified.

The manual for the [tag-order](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-tag_002dorder_002c-completion-style) style suggests a simple solution:

> - If any value consists of only a hyphen, then only the tags specified in the other values are generated. Normally all tags not explicitly selected are    tried last if the specified tags fail to generate any matches. This means that    a single value consisting only of a single hyphen turns off completion.

Applying the solution:

```
# Configure the order of tag matching as well as their descriptions.
zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            functions:Functions:Functions
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords"
           "-"
          )
'
```

Current behavior is:

- When I write `c` and hit the `TAB` key, I get the appropriate completions in correct order.

  [image])
- When I write `./` and hit the `TAB` key, I get nothing.

  [image]

---

Why is now only `executables` tag not working?

How can I fix it and get the desired behavior?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. You are missing some settings from your `.zshrc` that influence the behavior. An obvious one is `setopt menu_complete`, which I added. A harmless one is the escape character missing from the description format (tip: write `$'…\e[…'` instead of a literal escape character which is unprintable). Something else must be missing, because with the `-` I do get `directory` and `executable_file`. Also please give an example for “other tags will be tried as well”.

Comment: I don't use the `menu_complete` option as none of the completions were selected when I pressed the first `TAB` key(you probably meant the `auto_menu`, but that is specified by default). I am able to reproduce this while `.zshrc` contains only the code that I copied here. Maybe the distribution and `zsh` versions play a role? This is the output from `uname -a`: `Linux Arch 4.16.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 24 13:21:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. This is the output of `zsh --version`: `zsh 5.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. Thanks for the `$'...'`, I'll update the question.

Comment: Aha! The version does play a role. With the `"-"` version (and even without any `setopt`, the zstyle does seem to do the trick), I get `Executables` after `./` in zsh 5.0.7 but not in 5.1.1 or 5.4.2. I don't understand what's going on. With `set -x`, I do see a call to `_files -J Executables -X … -g '*(-*)'`, but it calls `_tags` which sees that the `tag-order` style contains a `-` and so decides not to do completions. I don't understand what's going on there. That part of `_tags` is identical in 5.0.7.

Comment: In 5.0.7, `_command_names` calls `_path_files`, whereas in later versions it calls `_files`. It's due to [this commit](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/9a4e1bf93b0bd60b39bb59fb9bc603cfe891b2d1), which is indeed between 5.0.7 and 5.1.1. I haven't confirmed that this commit makes the difference but it's plausible. I don't understand if the behavior you're observing is intended.

Comment: I've answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185846/why-does-a-value-hyphen-in-tag-order-style-prevent-matching-of-the-exec/50396735#50396735

Comment: @Gilles Wow, you went deep! :D Thanks for getting so involved in my question! The guy answered this question fully on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185846/why-does-a-value-hyphen-in-tag-order-style-prevent-matching-of-the-exec so if you are interested, you can see his answer.

Comment: Casting a close vote due to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50185846/4957508

Comment: @JeffSchaller To be honest, I think it's much more reasonable for this question to stay here and/or on Super User then it is to stay on StackOverflow. I would much rather remove it from StackOverflow.

Comment: Up to you! This site just has a “no cross posting” policy.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Should i `flag` it or `delete` it? Also, where is it more appropriate to stay, here or Super User?

Comment: I have flaged the same questions on both `StackOverflow` and `SuperUser`. Therefore, `DO NOT` close it here as well, because there won't be any instance left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executable` tag invokes `_files -g '*(-*)` in this case. Then `_files` calls more `_tags`, so it would be necessary to specify these *implicitly specified tags in the completion functions*, too.

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            functions:Functions:Functions
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords
            globbed-files directories"
           "-"
          )
'
```

It would be useful to add `globbed-files` and `directories` in this case:

```
% ls -al
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  3 t    t     4096 May 18 08:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 69632 May 18 15:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 t    t     4096 May 18 08:27 directory
-rwxr-xr-x  1 t    t        0 May 18 08:27 executable-file
-rw-r--r--  1 t    t        0 May 18 08:27 test
% ./<TAB>
Executables
directory/        executable-file*
```

---

But on the above setting, directories and local executable files will go into the same "Executable" group. If we would like to make "directories" go into other groups, we could specify the [`file-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-file_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) directly and use it like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' file-patterns \
 '*(#q-*):executables:Executables *(-/):directories:Directories'

zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            functions:Functions:Functions
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords
            directories:Directories"
            -
          )
'
```

In the below example, "directory" and "executable-file" are in the separated groups:

```
% ls -al
total 80
drwxr-xr-x  3 t    t     4096 May 18 08:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 69632 May 18 15:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 t    t     4096 May 18 08:27 directory
-rwxr-xr-x  1 t    t        0 May 18 08:27 executable-file
-rw-r--r--  1 t    t        0 May 18 08:27 test
% ./<TAB>
Executables
executable-file*
Directories
directory/
```

---

Below is the resulted smallest .zshrc example:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%F{black}%d%f%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' menu 'select'

# This comment out block is just for a reminder of my answer's first half.
# zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
#       reply=(
#                    "executables:Executables:Executables
#                       builtins:Builtins:Builtins
#                       commands:Commands:Commands
#                       aliases:Aliases:Aliases
#                       functions:Functions:Functions
#                       parameters:Variables:Variables
#                       reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords
#                       globbed-files directories"
#                    "-"
#                   )
# '

zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' file-patterns \
 '*(#q-*):executables:Executables *(-/):directories:Directories'

zstyle -e ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' tag-order '
    reply=(
           "executables:Executables:Executables
            builtins:Builtins:Builtins
            commands:Commands:Commands
            aliases:Aliases:Aliases
            functions:Functions:Functions
            parameters:Variables:Variables
            reserved-words:Keywords:Keywords
            directories:Directories"
            -
          )
'
```

Updated: comment out the unecessary block.

Comment: I've copied from my original answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50403671/4387039